# Mined blocks with reserved space for old utxos

Tags: mining-profitability, getblocktemplate, coin-age-priority

I've heard that long time ago. Getblocktemplate or it's equivalent at that time reserved a small space on blocks for old utxos instead of following the rule of ordering transactions by its sat/Byte for the full block. ¿Does somebody have any information about it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I've found this:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-high-priority-transaction-tara-annison, check out the comments since they have useful links.

It seems 50kb of block space was reserved for high priority transactions: a tx with (Sum (Value of input * Input Age) / Transaction Size) > 57,600,000

This seems to be a attempt to reserve a non-spammable space in blocks. Since equation above is a good heuristic to identify honest transactions.